# JSON Javascript object property returns undefined although a log of the object shows it being there

Tags: javascript, json

This is a very strange one. I am just console.logging and object and it's property like so:

```
console.log(DATASTORAGE, DATASTORAGE.dealObj);
```

A screenshot of the output is below:

[image]

Note that although the object is made via Ajax, the execution of this code is only on callback. This is driving me nuts! Please help.

Comment: please provide more details on your DATASTORAGE object

Comment: You mean that `DATASTORAGE.dealObj` is throwing "DATASTORAGE is undefined" error? Do you call that code more than once? We need more details..

Comment: The code is run 3 times (so far). I am outputting 2 things DATASTORAGE and DATASTORAGE.dealObj next to each other. DATASTORAGE is outputting as expected (with the dealObj displayed) DATASTORAGE.dealObj is returning undefined. I have also tried console.logging the 2 things on different lines & it has the same result.

Comment: As some futher info, all the other properties of DATASTORAGE also return undefined apart from 'regions'

Answer (score 0):

That is just saying that the return value of `console.log` is `undefined`

Comment: Would that display _below_ the other logged object?

Comment: Don't think thats it, the undefined is definitely the value of DATASTORAGE.dealObj

Comment: @Quentin: It does for me: http://i.imgur.com/HPjSO.png The first `undefined` there is the one that I logged; the second one is the return value of `console.log()` and appears on a separate line.